# "AddReward" not adding reward: Unity mlagents

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm working with "mlagents" with unity at the moment, but I ran into a problem.

Problem: When I call the function "AddReward", the Cumulative Reward does not go higher then the value i put in the "()"

for example:

```
AddReward(0.1f); //--- I add a reward
Debug.Log(GetCumulativeReward()); //--- Print Cumulative Reward
```

When i call this function it just jumps to 0.1 and stays there, even if I call it again, and the same if i put "-0.1" in (it jumps to -0.1 and stays there)

What i have treid:

1. Made sure I called "AddReward" and not "SetReward"
2. Used "SetReward" and just put "GetCumulativeReward() + 1" in the "()"

Both did not work

any fixes?

Update: GetCumulativeReward() Retruns the reward for that episode, not al the  episodes, so there was not probelm

Comment: Can you post AddReward() Function, so we can see where the problem is. Currently you didn't give us any clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: GetCumulativeReward() Retruns the reward for that episode, not al the  episodes, so there was not probelm